# Are both of these flowers chrysanthemums?

Tags: identification, flowers, perennials

I was told that both of these plants (they grow as neighbors in the same bed) are chrysanthemums, and that one is an annual and the other is a perennial kind.

Could that be right and if so what are the two specific kinds?

**UPDATE** A look at [this](http://www.deliflor.nl/Assortiment/Overzicht) assortment suggests that both plants may indeed be chrysanthemums but I am still interested in an expert opinion.

[image]
[image]

Comment: They do indeed look like mums, but is it possible for you to get some more complete pics?

Comment: @J.Musser They are all gone now, so unfortunately I can't provide better pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like both are mums, yes. But to me, it looks like they are both perennials. Look at the leaves. They both have the leaf type of [*Chrysanthemum x morifolium*](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/chrysanthemum-x-morifolium-cv-66115.html), which is what perennial garden mums are based on. Look at the edges of this leaf:

[image]

There are many kinds of mums, but this leaf with a large/showy flower signifies a plant that was developed from *Chrysanthemum x morifolium*.

Comment: If you could find one, a photo of an annual Chrysanthemum leaf would be useful for contrast with the perennial type.

Comment: @NiallC. There are dozens of species of annual mum, I guess I could just pick one.